# how assign a const to be used in all js file functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, syntax, vuex

Im working with

> `vuex` + `firebase`, so my `vuex` file has many `let db =
>   firebase.firestore()`
>
> so i would like to set 'const to all file' db = `firebase.firestore()`

how can i deal with this?

Comment: window.db=firebase.firestore(); // window.db will be available everywhere.

Comment: didn't understand.

Comment: vuex is a .js file, so db is a 'const'

Answer (score 0):

Where you defined `db`, you have to export it as follows (ES6):

`export const db = firebase.firestore();`

Then you will be able to use it in your JS files by simply calling it

`import db from 'your path'`